# Show advertisement at regular interval of time when iPhone is running

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on the app that shows **Ads (Video or image)** when iPhone is running. If I open any app(eg. Twitter) then also my Ads should be visible at particular interval of time. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

No. Your app will not be informed about any other apps being launched. Even if it were, you can't "force-grab" the foreground to display videos. That would totally violate any user interface principle established by iOS.

Besides the technical aspect I'd have my doubts of such an app surviving app review in general, though I don't know the specific part of the TOS right now.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show your ads inside your application in intervals or in any pattern you like. However it is not possible to bring your app to foreground when in background to play ads, it is actually not recommended at all. Best thing you can do is set a timer when the app gets in background to send a notification.